# WebRTC Chrome video is black, how to debug?

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to build a test app to test server SRTP decode-encode, in client, it create one PeerConnection, it provide the OFFER(actpass mode), server gives the ANSWER(passive mode).
The test app will decrypt the received RTP data and re-encrypt and send back to client.
I expected to see my local video echoed back, but the video is black.

I want through the negotiation part, the remote SDP has been set correctly, the remote video is added and connected. I also captured the network traffic, I checked the STUN/DTLS parts are completed successfully. In the test app, I found the srtp decrypt has all success, and re-encrypt without error.

How can I debug why it is still black? decode failure? I guess the SRTP decrypt is successful because if I give wrong SRTP data, it will print srtp failed in chrome_debug.log

Comment: Shooting from the hip: Have you set autoplay at the receiver? <video autoplay>

Comment: yes, I set autoplay, the same javascript works when the stream (RTP data) comes from Firefox!

Comment: BTW, I tested with the same test app with FF26, it can work!